# Trying to not freeze UI using async / await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, udp

I am trying not to freeze UI.

I used async / await, but it occurs InvalidOperationException, other thread owned this function. (I translated in english so it might be strange sentence)

```
public async void MimSetHeight(int _id, double _value)
{
   int index;
   index = Mim.FindIndex(mim => mim.ID == _id);
   if(mim.Count > index)
   {
      mim[index].ShapeHeight = _value;
      await Task.Delay(1000);
      mim[index].Shape.Height = _value; // <- Exception occurs
   }
}
```

```
switch(receivePacket.Data[1])
{
   case 53:
      Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke( () => 
           mim.MimSetHeight(5, Convert.ToInt32(Encoding.Default.GetString(receivePacket.Data))));
})));
}
```

I am feeling i should use Dispatcher.Invoke in last sentence.

Are there any other solution?

Comment: Is this for a UI program, or are you using some kind of COM objects? Is the method called from the UI thread? `await` should continue execution on the same 'context', i.e. UI thread or threadpool. So `Dispatcher.Invoke` should not be needed unless you are explicitly asking to run code on the threadpool. So I would place a breakpoint where the exception occur and check what thread it runs on.

Comment: It wasn't for UI program.

Comment: The `Dispatcher.Invoke` should be done *after* the `await`. Doing it before is unnecessary as you're still in the UI thread

Comment: You should move the ```Dispatcher.Invoke``` call from the second code block to the first one. There is no need to block the UI thread for a second. Instead do the minimum of UI work in the dispatcher code, such as updating properties.